# How to configure OpenLDAP server and test using Apache HTTPD

Tags: apache-2.2, ldap, centos6, openldap

I am using CentOS 6.  I found a [great article](http://docs.adaptivecomputing.com/viewpoint/hpc/Content/topics/1-setup/installSetup/settingUpOpenLDAPOnCentos6.htm) on how to install and configure OpenLDAP on CentOS 6, and I found some other great documentation [here](http://www.yolinux.com/TUTORIALS/LinuxTutorialApacheAddingLoginSiteProtection.html) on how to configure LDAP to work on Apache HTTPD (I am using 2.2, which comes with CentOS 6).  Unfortunately, what both articles do not necessarily specify is how to connect the two together.  The second article I mentioned is great for an Apache walk through assuming you already have a good understanding of LDAP syntax, and the first article I mentioned is great assuming you already have in mind a way to test it.  It seems like you have to be an expert at one or the other for either walk through to get you completely set up.

So let's assume that I configured my LDAP credentials according to the CentOS OpenLDAP walk-through article.  I have added the following folks:

**acme.ldif**

```
dn: dc=acme,dc=com
objectClass: dcObject
objectClass: organization
dc: acme
o : acme
```

**users.ldif**

```
dn: ou=Users,dc=acme,dc=com
objectClass: organizationalUnit
ou: Users
```

**bob.ldif**

```
dn: cn=Bob Jones,ou=Users,dc=acme,dc=com
cn: Bob Jones
sn: Jones
objectClass: inetOrgPerson
userPassword: p@ssw0rd
uid: bjones
```

**engineering.ldif**

```
dn: cn=Engineering,ou=Users,dc=acme,dc=com
cn: Engineering
objectClass: groupOfNames
member: cn=Bob Jones,ou=Users,dc=acme,dc=com
```

**addUserToGroup.ldif**

```
dn: cn=Engineering,ou=Users,dc=acme,dc=com
changetype: modify
add: member
member: cn=Al Smith,ou=Users,dc=acme,dc=com
```

**al.ldif**

```
dn: cn=Al Smith,ou=Users,dc=acme,dc=com
cn: Al Smith
sn: Smith
objectClass: inetOrgPerson
userPassword: 12345
uid: asmith
```

I downloaded LDAPExplorer Tool 2 from SourceForge and successfully connected to this LDAP directory and explored it, and it looks just like the LDIF files suggest.

The following is from my httpd.conf file for Apache HTTPD:

```
<Directory /var/www/html/authpage>
    AuthType Basic
    AuthName "Enter valid user name"
    AuthLDAPURL ldap://magneto.acme.com:389/????
    require valid-user
</Directory>
```

Where the `????` is is where I do not know how to make my LDAP syntax line up with my LDAP directory.  I have tried all sorts.  What happens is I navigate to the URL `http://magneto.acme.com/authpage` (magneto is my hostname for the server in this case, I at least know that works), and I am prompted for credentials.  Nothing I put in works.  I have tried combinations of `ou=` and `o=` and `dc=`, along with `?uid` as the query parameter.

When I check my Apache `error_log`, I see this line:

```
[Wed Sep 10 11:00:51 2014] [error] [client 10.78.182.243] access to /authpage failed, reason: verification of user id 'bjones' not configured
[Wed Sep 10 11:00:54 2014] [error] [client 10.78.182.243] access to /authpage failed, reason: verification of user id 'asmith' not configured
```

Assuming my LDAP directory works, and that Apache is correctly trying to authenticate to it, 
1. How do I write correct syntax to authenticate to *all users*, or just a specific group?
2. Is there any additional configuration required to configure verification of users, based on what the `error_log` said?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After even more searching, I found [this article](http://archive09.linux.com/feature/120050) that gave just a bit more information.  It turns out I was just missing a few important lines from my Apache HTTPD `httpd.conf` file:

```
<Directory /var/www/html/authpage>
    Order deny,allow
    Deny from All
    AuthName "Enter valid user name"
    AuthType Basic
    AuthBasicProvider ldap
    AuthzLDAPAuthoritative off
    AuthLDAPUrl ldap://magneto.acme.com/ou=Users,dc=acme,dc=com?uid
    Require valid-user
    Satisfy any
</Directory>
```

Hopefully if there is ever anyone in the future who is on CentOS 6 and using OpenLDAP and setting up LDAP authentication through Apache HTTPD, the links in this ServerFault post will help shed some light.  That took quite a bit of trial, error, and searching.

Answer (score 2):

```
ldap://host:port/basedn?attribute?scope?filter
```

In your case:

```
AuthLDAPURL ldap://magneto.acme.com:389/ou=Users,dc=acme,dc=com?uid?sub?(objectClass=inetOrgPerson)
```

**Note:** if you do not allow anonymous searchs on your LDAP server, you may need to configure `AuthLDAPBindDN` and `AuthLDAPBindPassword`